# Web application using the Slim API. I'm trying to get data from my SQL database to populate a modal when the edit link is clicked in the table

Tags: json, ajax, rest, bootstrap-modal, slim

Whilst debugging; the id for each row is found when the edit button is clicked but it seems to get stuck at that point. The data for the said row will not populate the modal. I would appreciate any help at all! [Here is a picture in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwGqi.png). I have exhausted all of my ideas. I do have an error for localhost failed to load resource for an image folder, could this be causing conflict? I don't see how.

> HTML

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="admin">
                    <br>
                    <div class="container">
                        <table id="admin_table" class="display">
                            <thead>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Genre</th>
                                    <th>Platform</th>
                                    <th>Score Phrase</th>
                                    <th>Score</th>
                                    <th>Release Year</th>
                                    <th>Release Month</th>
                                    <th>Release Day</th>
                                    <th>Editors Choice</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>x</th>

                                </tr>

                                <tbody id="admin_table_body">

                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div> <br><br><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
>Modal      

 <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
                  </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>ID:</strong></label>
                            <input type="text" style="height:32px;" name="id" id="id" disabled/>
                            <label for="id" class="error"></label>
                        </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Title:</strong></label>
                                <input type="text" style="height:32px;" id="title" name="title"/>
                           <label for="title" class="error" ></label>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Genre:</strong></label>
                            <input type="text" style="height:32px;" id="genre" name="genre"/>
                            <label for="genre" class="error" ></label>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">

                           <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Platform:</strong></label>
                           <input type="text" style="height:32px;" id="platform" name="platform"/>
                           <label for="platform" class="error" ></label>
                        </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Score:</strong></label>
                            <input type="text" id="score" name="score" style="height:32px;"/>
                            <label for="score" class="error"></label>
                       </div>   
                                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Score Phrase:</strong></label>
                            <input type="text" id="score_phrase" name="score_phrase" style="height:32px;"/>
                            <label for="score_phrase" class="error"></label>
                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Release Year:</strong></label>
                            <input type="text" id="release_year" name="release_year" style="height:32px;"/>
                            <label for="release_year" class="error"></label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Release Month:</strong></label>
                            <textarea id="release_month" name="release_month" style="height:32px;"></textarea>
                            <label for="release_month" class="error"></label>
                       </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Release Day:</strong></label>
                            <textarea id="release_day" name="release_day" style="height:32px;"></textarea>
                            <label for="release_day" class="error"></label>
                       </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><strong>Editors Choice:</strong></label>
                            <textarea id="editors_choice" name="editors_choice" style="height:32px;"></textarea>
                            <label for="editors_choice" class="error"></label>
                       </div>
                    </form>
          </div>
```

> Main.js

```
        var rootURL ="http://localhost:4006/GamesAPI/api/games";
        var currentGame;
        //when the DOM is ready
        $(document).ready(function(){
            findAll();
            //findById();
            $(document).on("click","#admin_table_body a",function(){findById(this.id);});
           // $(document).on("click","#addButton",function(){addGame();});
           // $(document).on("click","#deleteButton",function(){deleteGame();});

        });

        var findAll=function(){
            console.log('findAll');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: rootURL,
                dataType: "json", // data type of response
                success: renderList
            });
        };

        var findById = function(id)
        {
            console.log('findById: '+id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: rootURL + '/' + id,
                dataType: "json",
                //Gets stuck here
                success: function(data){
                    //$('#btnDelete').show();
                    console.log('findById success: ' +data.title);
                    currentGame = data;
                    renderDetails(currentGame);

                }


            });
        };


        function renderList(data){
            list = data.games;
            console.log("renderList");
            $('#admin_table_body tr').remove();
            $.each(list, function(index, games){
                $('#admin_table_body').append('<tr><td>' +games.title+'</td><td>'+games.genre+'</td><td>' 
                        +games.platform+'</td><td>' +games.score_phrase+'</td><td>'
                        +games.score+'</td><td>'+games.release_year+'</td><td>'+games.release_month+'</td><td>'
                        +games.release_day+'</td><td>'+games.editors_choice+'</td><td>\n\
                        <a href="#"  id="'+games.id+'" "span class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</a></td>\n\
                        <td id="'+games.id+'"><button type="button" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-success">Delete</button></td></tr>');
            });
            $('#admin_table').DataTable();


           // $('gameList').append('<div class="row">');

           //The rest of this function is to populate a different client page
           output='<div class="row">';
            $.each(list, function(index,games){
                var img="pics/"+games.picture;
                output+=('<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="card"><img src='+'"'+img+'"'+
                        'height="150"><p>Title: '+games.title+'</p><p>Genre: '+games.genre+'</p><p>Platform: '+games.platform+
                        '</p><p>Score: '+games.score+'  '+games.score_phrase+'</p></div></div>');
              // $('#gameList').append('<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><div class="card">'+game.title+'</div></div>');
           }); 
         // $('#gameList').append('</div>');
           output+='</div>';
           $('#productList').append(output);
            }; 


        var renderDetails = function(games)
        {
            $('#id').val(games.id);
            $('#title').val(games.title);
            $('#url').val(games.url);
            $('#platform').val(games.platform);
            $('#score').val(games.score);
            $('#score_phrase').val(games.score_phrase);
            $('#genre').val(games.genre);
            $('#pic').attr('src', 'pics/' + games.picture);
            $('#editors_choice').val(games.editors_choice);
            $('#release_year').val(games.release_year);
            $('#release_month').val(games.release_month);
            $('#release_day').val(games.release_day);

        };
```

> DatabaseMethod.php

```
function getGame($id) { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = '$id'";
    try {
        global $db;
        $games = $db->query($query);  
        $game = $games->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
        echo $query;
                echo json_encode($game);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "gets stuck here" (comment in the code)?? Does the "success" function execute? Is anything logged in the console? Is it what you expected? If not, then what _does_ happen? Does the ajax request complete? Does it return an OK (200) status? What's in the response? Again, if not, what happens instead? "gets stuck" or "will not populate" really aren't adequate debugging info to be able to help with the problem. There's a lot of code here, so we need to pinpoint the problem, and also we can't see your server method, or any of your data which might be playing a part.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clear information. The 'success' function does not execute. The 'id' gets logged into the console and an OK(200) status is returned with the URL of the data; 'http://localhost:4006/GamesAPI/api/games/145'.

Comment: If it returns 200 OK, but "success" does not run, that doesn't make any sense, unless perhaps you're getting a console error whereby the response data is un-parseable? Like I said, what's in the response to that call (look inside the ajax request, in your network tab)? Is it valid JSON, and what you expected? If the ajax call runs, and returns 200 OK then "success" will always execute unless the returned data cannot be interpreted as valid JSON.

Comment: Ok, yes the valid JSON is returned.

Comment: Can you show me the data? Because it seems pretty strange that the function would not do anything.

Comment: BTW you should not be concatenating $id into your SQL query like that - it makes you potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IEfQU

Thank you, I will make the necessary security changes later.

Comment: Actually it's the contents of the "Response" tab which would be more interesting. Whatever is in there certainly isn't JSON, or at least not verifiably so from the way it's being displayed by Chrome.

Comment: SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = '145'{"id":"145","score_phrase":"Bad","title":"007 Legends","url":"\/games\/007-legends\/xbox-360-132394","platform":"Xbox 360","score":"4.5","genre":"Action","editors_choice":"N","release_year":"2012","release_month":"10","release_day":"16","picture":""}

Is this select string causing the problem?

Comment: yeah that's not valid JSON.  Don't echo the query in your PHP. I just noticed `echo $query;`, remove that, I guess it was just left in for debugging? Your browser assumes the entire content of the response is JSON and tries to parse it as such. If it can't understand the whole thing as JSON, it'll fail to decode any of it, because it doesn't know which part is supposed to be correct. Weird you don't have a console error about it, though.

Comment: Awesome! I left the 'echo $query;' in there for debugging earlier in the project. Thank you so much, I appreciate your time and help <3

I can finally move on to the final requirements.

Comment: No worries, I added that as the answer, I'd be grateful if you could upvote and/or mark accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server-side PHP method is outputting data which is not valid JSON.

Remove

```
echo $query;
```

from your code, since it's just left over from debugging. This is preventing jQuery from seeing the whole response as JSON and parsing it accordingly.